# O que são realmente os conjuntos de modificações do Git?

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou começando agora a usar o Git e uma coisa que eu ouvi no curso que estou vendo foi o seguinte: o que o Git realmente guarda não são as diferentes versões dos arquivos, mas sim conjuntos de modificações.

Dessa forma, ao fazer um `commit`, ao invés de salvar no repositório os arquivos no estado que eles estão, o que eu entendi disso é que o Git salva no repositório um conjunto de modificações contendo as modificações que foram realizadas.

#### A minha dúvida

As modificações são com relação a qual estado do projeto? O estado inicial ou o estado do último commit?

O que eu quero dizer basicamente é o seguinte: suponhamos que logo após criarmos o repositório adicionamos um arquivo `arquivo1.txt`, ao fazermos o commit, a modificação que o Git vai registrar é a criação desse arquivo. Após isso criamos um novo arquivo `arquivo2.txt` e adicionamos uma linha ao `arquivo1.txt` e fazemos um commit.

Nesse caso o que o Git salva no segundo commit? A modificação registrada é a adição do `arquivo2.txt` e a adição da linha (ou seja, relativa a ultima modificação) ou é a adição do arquivo `arquivo1.txt` e do `arquivo2.txt` bem como a modificação no primeiro arquivo (ou seja, a modificação total a partir do estado inicial)?

Me parece que o que o Git salva é na verdade a modificação com relação a última modificação, já que se ele salvasse a modificação relativa ao estado inicial seria equivalente a guardar as diferentes versões dos arquivos em si.

Eu realmente não estou entendendo muito bem ainda o que são esses conjuntos de modificação que o Git registra em cada commit. O que eles realmente são?

Comment: É isso que você está achando mesmo, ele salva em relação ao último commit.

Comment: Até porque a segunda opção (salvar tanto a nova versão completa do arquivo quanto as modificações neste arquivo) seria um registro redundante.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: aqui esta em portugues http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto, só não entendi uma coisa. Esse link que o Juarez passou diz que o Git salva na verdade snapshots, enquanto que os outros VCS's que salvam modificações nos arquivos. Se o Git salva snapshots, então na realidade ele tem em cada commit o estado exato de cada arquivo e não só as modificações certo? Acho que não entendi bem como essa ideia de snapshots se relaciona com o que eu vi no curso e comentei na questão.

Comment: Não, ele tem apenas as modificações, mas com elas é capaz de reproduzir toda a árvore do seu projeto em determinado commit. Não sei onde você leu isso, nem o que te ensinaram como "snapshot" no curso, mas tenha em mente que não se trata de um termo técnico, preciso. É uma metáfora para representar que é possível recuperar um "retrato" do seu projeto em diversas fases dele.

Comment: Na verdade no curso não se falou de snapshots, só de changesets, conjuntos de modificações que são salvos a cada commit. Foi nesse link http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control que eu vi agora falando de snapshots. A ideia então é que o repositório tem os conjuntos de modificação de cada commit e é possível obter esse "retrato" aplicando as modificações? Obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda!

Comment: @Leonardo hunm, começo a temer por este curso. Não é nada grave mas não gosto quando algo que formal tentando ensinar usa termos errados. O Git não trabalha com *changesets*, ele não tem essa capacidade. Eu não conheço muito o funcionamento interno destes softwares mas sei *changesets* são as modificações feitas nos arquivos agrupadas. *Snapshots* é um estado em um determinado tempo. Em tese seria uma cópia exata do arquivo naquele momento. Mas é possível trabalhar com uma codificação delta que acaba reproduzindo o mecanismo das diferenças mas por um método totalmente diferente.

Comment: Ninguém respondeu, arrisquei uma resposta.

Comment: @bigown eu também fiquei meio desconfiado do curso agora. Além do site oficial do Git também achei uns videos na MVA (http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/using-git-with-visual-studio-2013-jump-start) sobre Git que confirmam o uso de snapshots e não deltas.

Comment: Mas até onde eu sei os *snapshots* são obtidos através de deltas.

Comment: @Leonardo, fiz uma resposta porque as coisas estavam meio confusas por aqui. Espero ter deixado claro o que é changeset, snapshot, como o Git guarda os arquivos no momento do commit e como ocorre a substituição do conteúdo do arquivo pelos registros de alterações no arquivo. Se algo não ficou muito claro por favor avise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estes termos nem sempre são usados da maneira correta.

O Git utiliza *snapshot* que é um estado do conteúdo em determinado momento, por isto também é conhecido como *point in time*. Estes *snapshots* são de todo o repositório. Daí existe uma limitação no Git para que qualquer atualização afete todo o repositório e alguns artifícios (*stash* por exemplo*) devem ser utilizados para evitar que parte do conteúdo que está sendo manipulado seja confirmado no repositório.

Para que não tenha que armazenar todo o conteúdo novo em cada *commit* realizado um mecanismo diferencial é utilizado e apenas uma [codificação delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) de cada alteração é armazenada. Estes diferenciais são obtidos entre a versão anterior e a atual. Ainda assim os repositórios existem por si só. Esta forma permite várias linhas de desenvolvimento competirem simultaneamente.

Outros softwares de controle de versão podem usar os *changesets* ou conjuntos de modificações. Estes são os diferenciais entre o que existia no repositório e o que está sendo confirmado agora. Esta sutil diferença dificulta trabalhar com várias fontes de alterações concorrentes. Mas facilita confirmar as alterações de forma parcial. Desta forma é possível facilmente selecionar o que quer confirmar e montar um conjunto de modificações só com o que deseja naquele momento. Os repositórios são montados a partir das suas alterações.

Estritamente falando no Git não podemos fazer de conjunto de modificações. Informalmente este termo acaba sendo usado.

Eu não conheço profundamente os mecanismos destes softwares e não é fácil achar definições que não gerem confusões. Aparentemente eu não sou o único que não se sentiu impedido de falar sobre algo que não conhece em todos os detalhes :P. É fácil achar informações contraditórias sobre o assunto. Mas de acordo com a documentação mais conhecida é assim que funciona.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @bigown, já estou convencido que o Git usa snapshots mesmo. Além do que você falou, pesquisei um pouco e olhei na pasta .git/objects, fiz uns testes e usei ruby pra ver o conteúdo dos arquivos. Daí olhando os blobs parece que a cada commit ele salva o conteúdo todo de cada arquivo, e quando não muda só referencia o que já tinha. Agora não entendi muito bem isso que você falou de armazenar apenas uma codificação delta. Pelo que eu vi lá nos blobs parece que ele salva tudo mesmo. Você sabe como que funciona isso no Git? Muito obrigado mais uma vez, ajudou muito!

Comment: Você fez uma alteração no arquivo, tipo, mudou uma linha, um caractere do conteúdo dele, e viu como ficou? É para ter apenas o diferencial. Eu nunca fiz o que você tentou e não tenho o Git aqui para fazer mas a ideia é boa para entender o funcionamento, só precisa testar em cenários diferentes. Eu me surpreenderia muito se ele realmente salvasse o arquivo todo por caus de uma alteração pequena. O Git ocupa bem pouco espaço, menos até do que softwares que usam *changesets*. E já li algo mostrando que ele faz o *diff* das alterações que é este delta. Só não sei onde tem algo autoritativo.

Comment: Fiz isso mesmo, criei primeiro um arquivo `arquivo1.txt` e adicionei algum conteúdo, aí fiz um commit. Depois editei ele e escrevi um pouco mais de conteúdo, e fiz outro commit. Quando olhei os blobs, no blob correspondente ao arquivo no segundo commit ele salvou o conteúdo todo. Achei isso http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles na página do git, pelo que entendi o git pode usar deltas pra ocupar menos espaço. Acho que ele faz isso automaticamente quando precisa.

Comment: Pode ser isto mesmo. Ele deve saber quando não vale à pena ou não pode por alguma razão.

Answer (score 5):

Complementando as outras respostas, acho que vale a pena ver internamente como o Git guarda tais informações, pois aí conseguimos entender melhor o que é feito no caso de um arquivo ser modificado, e o que realmente é guardado em cada *commit*. Para isso vamos usar alguns comandos chamados de [*plumbing*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) (os que lidam com os detalhes mais internos, considerados *low level*).

---

## Introdução

Primeiramente, vale lembrar que no fundo um repositório do Git é um DAG (*Directed Acyclic Graph* - Grafo Acíclico Dirigido). Não vou entrar nos detalhes da definição matemática (que pode ser vista [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)), mas basicamente podemos pensar em um repositório do Git como sendo um conjunto de nós apontando para outros nós. E esses nós podem ser de vários tipos: commits, arquivos, etc. Cada um desses nós tem um identificador único, que são os hashes (aqueles "códigos gigantes", como `65e02ed772a5fa35a98409705fd43647af454443`).

De maneira geral, um nó do tipo commit aponta para outro(s) commit(s) (os commits pais - sim, quando é feito um merge, o commit resultante pode ter mais de um pai), mas também aponta para uma árvore de diretórios (chamado de *tree*), que por sua vez aponta para os arquivos referentes àquele commit.

[image: repositório Git]

---

## Criando o repositório e analisando sua estrutura interna

No exemplo abaixo criaremos um repositório e iremos ver as "entranhas" do mesmo, usando os comandos de *plumbing*.

> *Os comandos abaixo foram rodados em Ubuntu 20.04.4 e Git 2.37.3. Em outras versões pode ser que a saída de alguns comandos seja diferente, com outras mensagens, etc. Mas a ideia básica permanece a mesma.*

Primeiro vamos criar uma pasta e inicializar um novo repositório nela:

```bash
$ mkdir projeto 
$ cd projeto/
$ git init
```

Com isso ele cria um repositório vazio. Se olharmos na pasta do projeto, veremos que foi criada uma pasta `.git`. É ali que o Git guarda as informações do repositório.

Em seguida vamos criar um arquivo e *commitá-lo*:

```bash
$ echo abc > arquivo1.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m"criar arquivo1.txt"
[master (root-commit) 90e5167] criar arquivo1.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 arquivo1.txt
```

Com isso temos o primeiro commit:

```bash
$ git log
commit 90e5167946367108cc2b6185b7c943581336c23a
Author: Fulano <fulano@mail.com>
Date:   2022-09-01 08:27:31

    criar arquivo1.txt
```

E agora podemos usar o hash do commit (o código gigante `90e5167946367108cc2b6185b7c943581336c23a`), juntamente com o [comando `cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) para ver mais detalhes do mesmo:

```bash
$ git cat-file -p 90e5167946367108cc2b6185b7c943581336c23a
tree 3cbbb46b2c176c87ebb4bc286447deb26a45f196
author Fulano <fulano@mail.com> 1662031651 -0300
committer Fulano <fulano@mail.com> 1662031651 -0300

criar arquivo1.txt
```

Repare que o commit aponta para um objeto *tree* (indicado pela linha que começa com `tree`), que representa uma árvore de arquivos e sub-diretórios. Podemos ver que este objeto *tree* também tem um hash, que pode ser usado com `cat-file` para sabermos mais detalhes dele:

```bash
$ git cat-file -p 3cbbb46b2c176c87ebb4bc286447deb26a45f196
100644 blob 8baef1b4abc478178b004d62031cf7fe6db6f903    arquivo1.txt
```

Como podemos ver, o objeto *tree* contém apenas uma referência para um objeto do tipo *blob*, que no caso é o conteúdo do arquivo1.txt (que também possui seu próprio hash). E se fizermos `git cat-file -p 8baef1b4abc478178b004d62031cf7fe6db6f903`, ele mostrará o conteúdo deste arquivo (no caso, o texto `abc` mais a quebra de linha).

Mas também podemos ver o seu conteúdo diretamente, lendo o respectivo arquivo que está na pasta `.git/objects`. Como o Git usa o zlib para compactar os arquivos, temos que descompactá-los:

```bash
$ zlib-flate -uncompress < .git/objects/8b/aef1b4abc478178b004d62031cf7fe6db6f903 
blob 4abc
```

<sup><sub>*Para usar `zlib-flate`, basta instalá-lo com `sudo apt install qpdf`. [Existem outras formas de descompactar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22834), mas foge do escopo da resposta.*</sub></sup>

Repare que o conteúdo do arquivo é o tipo (no caso, "blob"), um espaço, o tamanho (`4`) e o conteúdo do arquivo (o texto `abc` e a quebra de linha, por isso que o tamanho é 4). Na verdade, depois do tamanho tem um byte zero, que é usado como separador, para indicar que depois dali é o conteúdo do arquivo. Se quiser "escovar os bits" para ver melhor, pode usar algum comando como o `hexdump`:

```bash
$ zlib-flate -uncompress < .git/objects/8b/aef1b4abc478178b004d62031cf7fe6db6f903 | hexdump -C
00000000  62 6c 6f 62 20 34 00 61  62 63 0a                 |blob 4.abc.|
0000000b
```

Ali podemos ver o byte `00` logo depois do tamanho, e a quebra de linha (`0a`) no final.

E agora vamos ver o que acontece ao modificar o arquivo.

---

Vamos alterar o arquivo1.txt e adicionar um novo arquivo2.txt:

```bash
$ echo def >> arquivo1.txt 
$ echo xyz > arquivo2.txt
$ git add .
$ git c -m"mudar arquivo1, adicionar arquivo2"
[master 6759854] mudar arquivo1, adicionar arquivo2
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 arquivo2.txt
$ git log --format=oneline 
67598546881d02d1642cb0a2bd7093f0686cfa16 mudar arquivo1, adicionar arquivo2
90e5167946367108cc2b6185b7c943581336c23a criar arquivo1.txt
```

Foi criado um novo commit. Vamos usar `cat-file` para ver qual é o objeto *tree* deste, e também para ver os arquivos desta *tree*:

```bash
# ver detalhes do commit
$ git cat-file -p 67598546881d02d1642cb0a2bd7093f0686cfa16
tree a68b978e09a6ff8b29160d8005bdcd3b5f71c86a
parent 90e5167946367108cc2b6185b7c943581336c23a
author Fulano <fulano@mail.com> 1662033566 -0300
committer Fulano <fulano@mail.com> 1662033566 -0300

mudar arquivo1, adicionar arquivo2

# ver detalhes da tree do commit
$ git cat-file -p a68b978e09a6ff8b29160d8005bdcd3b5f71c86a
100644 blob 5f5521fae22f9e33657c85e468d7bdd43f7350d8    arquivo1.txt
100644 blob cd470e619003f5e55999473fec485d85a8601e44    arquivo2.txt
```

Agora o commit aponta para uma nova *tree*, que por sua vez aponta para os arquivos `arquivo1.txt` e `arquivo2.txt`. Veja que o hash do arquivo1 mudou, já que ele foi alterado e portanto corresponde a um novo objeto *blob*.

<sup>*Interessante notar também que agora o commit possui um *parent*, que nada mais é que o "commit pai" (ou seja, o commit anterior).*</sup>

Porém, a versão anterior do arquivo1 continua existindo, tanto que podemos ver ambas com `cat-file`:

```bash
# versão atual do arquivo (segundo commit)
$ git cat-file -p 5f5521fae22f9e33657c85e468d7bdd43f7350d8
abc
def
# versão antiga (do primeiro commit)
$ git cat-file -p 8baef1b4abc478178b004d62031cf7fe6db6f903
abc
```

E podemos escovar os bits desses arquivos descompactando-os diretamente:

```bash
# versão atual
$ zlib-flate -uncompress < .git/objects/5f/5521fae22f9e33657c85e468d7bdd43f7350d8 
blob 8abc
def
# versão antiga
$ zlib-flate -uncompress < .git/objects/8b/aef1b4abc478178b004d62031cf7fe6db6f903 
blob 4abc
```

Podemos ver que as diferentes versões do arquivo estão armazenadas em sua totalidade (portanto, nada de *delta* aqui). **Inicialmente**, é assim que o Git guarda os arquivos: cada alteração no arquivo gera um novo objeto *blob*, e cada um deles possui todo o conteúdo do arquivo. Estes são chamados de *loose objects* (algo como "objetos soltos").

---

## *Packfiles*

Mas com o passar do tempo (conforme o repositório cresce e a quantidade de arquivos e alterações aumenta) o Git pode fazer o *packing* dos objetos, criando um *packfile*. Neste caso, ele pode fazer um *delta compression* no arquivo (já veremos isso em mais detalhes).

Para testar, eu criei mais 10 mil commits, sempre modificando o arquivo1:

```bash
$ for i in $(seq 1 10000); do echo $(date) >> arquivo1.txt && git commit -a -m"alterado em $(date)"; done
```

No caso, eu sempre adiciono uma linha nova contendo a data atual.
Vamos ver o último commit:

```bash
$ git log -1 --oneline 
a7006d04 alterado em qui 01 set 2022 09:41:48 -03
```

Primeiro vamos ver a *tree* e os arquivos para o qual ela aponta:

```bash
# ver detalhes do commit
$ git cat-file -p a7006d04
tree a1c5e63ce53ab84598db22080a5064458292bf2c
# ... demais linhas do commit (parent, autor, data, etc) ...

# ver tree
$ git cat-file -p a1c5e63ce53ab84598db22080a5064458292bf2c
100644 blob 78b67d43faf1675eb8885550211097271a4cc27b    arquivo1.txt
100644 blob cd470e619003f5e55999473fec485d85a8601e44    arquivo2.txt

# ver tamanho do arquivo1
$ git cat-file -s 78b67d43faf1675eb8885550211097271a4cc27b
290037

# descompacatar o arquivo1 e ver as 3 primeiras linhas
$ zlib-flate -uncompress < .git/objects/78/b67d43faf1675eb8885550211097271a4cc27b | head -3
blob 290037abc
def
qui 01 set 2022 09:36:14 -03
```

Repare que o arquivo referente a `78b67d43faf1675eb8885550211097271a4cc27b` ainda está compactado em `.git/objects`. Mas a seguir veremos que nem todos estarão.

> Um detalhe interessante é que, como o arquivo2 não foi modificado, a *tree* do último commit aponta para o mesmo *blob* que a *tree* do segundo commit. Ou seja, a *tree* de um commit sempre possui todas as entradas referentes à estrutura de arquivos completa. O que acontece é que, caso um arquivo não tenha sido modificado, não é criada outra cópia dele, e a *tree* aponta para o mesmo objeto *blob*.

---

Agora vamos ver um commit que foi colocado no *packfile* (veremos mais abaixo como eu descobri isso):

```bash
# ver detalhes do commit
$ git cat-file -p b2663a0ee53eecb9f364a9aa054f7b80d5734cb4
tree 35153e41fda0f4d3e50b67bf211a420c5e30883a
parent 4d223b4641d8ca59014d3c998bc3549210757cac
author Fulano <fulano@mail.com> 1662035948 -0300
committer Fulano <fulano@mail.com> 1662035948 -0300

alterado em qui 01 set 2022 09:39:08 -03

# ver detalhes da tree
$ git cat-file -p 35153e41fda0f4d3e50b67bf211a420c5e30883a
100644 blob 07e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb    arquivo1.txt
100644 blob cd470e619003f5e55999473fec485d85a8601e44    arquivo2.txt

# ver tamanho do arquivo1
$ git cat-file -s 07e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb
56181

# porém, o blob correspondente não está em .git/objects
$ ls .git/objects/07/e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb
ls: cannot access '.git/objects/07/e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb': No such file or directory
```

Note que o arquivo referente ao *blob* do arquivo1 não está em `.git/objects`. Então onde ele foi parar?

---

Já vimos que inicialmente cada alteração no arquivo gera um novo objeto *blob* (que por sua vez, é guardado em `.git/objects`).

Mas com o passar do tempo (conforme o repositório cresce e a quantidade de arquivos e alterações aumenta) o Git pode fazer o *packing* dos objetos, criando um *packfile*. E neste caso, ele pode fazer um *delta compression* no arquivo.

No nosso caso, em algum momento no meio daqueles 10 mil commits, o Git decidiu (usando suas heurísticas internas) criar este *packfile*, e o commit `b2663a0ee53eecb9f364a9aa054f7b80d5734cb4` é um dos que foram colocados neste arquivo. Na verdade, foram criados vários *packfiles*:

```bash
$ ls  .git/objects/pack/
pack-58b4d7c6d98f33d81c7eed8306c2c298680ab574.idx   pack-d838acaa7d25ce143e57c11aa85dd808ed924cbb.idx   pack-fe4498b7648c104a9f493c02b572ba8e6a234789.idx
pack-58b4d7c6d98f33d81c7eed8306c2c298680ab574.pack  pack-d838acaa7d25ce143e57c11aa85dd808ed924cbb.pack  pack-fe4498b7648c104a9f493c02b572ba8e6a234789.pack
pack-a549c672e7fe758144ac131b58d2d09e0436e70d.idx   pack-dbe28ff425c24fe667c00f087165e1ea88bb78f8.idx
pack-a549c672e7fe758144ac131b58d2d09e0436e70d.pack  pack-dbe28ff425c24fe667c00f087165e1ea88bb78f8.pack
```

Para ler um *packfile*, eu usei o comando `git verify-pack`. Rodando para cada um dos arquivos `.idx` (que são os índices de cada *packfile*), eu pude verificar onde está o commit:

```bash
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-fe4498b7648c104a9f493c02b572ba8e6a234789.idx | grep b2663a0ee53eecb9f364a9aa054f7b80d5734cb4
b2663a0ee53eecb9f364a9aa054f7b80d5734cb4 commit 269 177 264219
```

Assim, descobri que o commit `b2663a0ee53eecb9f364a9aa054f7b80d5734cb4` está no pack `fe4498b7648c104a9f493c02b572ba8e6a234789`. Este commit não está em `.git/objects/b2`, e sim no *packfile*. O mesmo vale para o arquivo1 que vimos acima, cujo hash `07e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb` também não está em `.git/objects`. Usando `verify-pack`, vemos que ele também está no *packfile*:

```bash
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-fe4498b7648c104a9f493c02b572ba8e6a234789.idx| grep 07e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb
07e93cacac5e6a412107e34ee8a9f6711db09cdb blob   9 21 417607 1 f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573
```

E aqui podemos ver algo interessante: a primeira coluna acima indica o hash do objeto, a segunda coluna é o tipo (`blob`) e a terceira coluna é o tamanho. Veja que ela só ocupa 9 bytes. E a última coluna é o hash do "arquivo-base". Segundo a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack#_output_format), esta coluna só aparece quando o objeto está "*deltificado*" (ou seja, está armazenado como um delta - ele não tem todo o conteúdo do arquivo, e sim apenas a diferença com relação a uma versão anterior).

E se procurarmos por este arquivo-base, veremos que muitos outros arquivos são um delta com relação a ele:

```bash
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-fe4498b7648c104a9f493c02b572ba8e6a234789.idx| grep f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573
f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573 blob   60328 380 397727
d282fe4a22cc541caf0a5f232a8ca1b06f9973b4 blob   9 21 398107 1 f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573
65e02ed772a5fa35a98409705fd43647af454443 blob   9 20 398206 1 f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573
cb59c4bdec5b293b6bade9b2a6131668a7e6700d blob   9 20 398304 1 f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573
402e6a7b054399adbfee3e4f223662607f1e8304 blob   9 20 398401 1 f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573
# ... muitos outros arquivos que tem f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573 como base
```

Na primeira linha podemos ver o arquivo `f762451817603f36e04f0d3fd429cab316232573`, ocupando 60328 bytes, e nas linhas seguintes os arquivos que estão armazenados como deltas em relação a ele, todos ocupando 9 bytes.

Se quisermos olhar algum desses arquivos, primeiro ele é reconstruído a partir da base, aplicando-se os deltas necessários (usando a quinta coluna, que é o *offset*: a posição no respectivo arquivo `.pack` onde os dados do objeto estão). Por exemplo, um dos deltas acima, que só ocupa 9 bytes no *packfile*, terá seu tamanho total calculado se usarmos `cat-file`:

```bash
$ git cat-file -s cb59c4bdec5b293b6bade9b2a6131668a7e6700d
59168
```

---

## Conclusão

Nos momentos iniciais do repositório, o Git armazena os arquivos como *loose objects*: cada versão do arquivo gera um novo objeto *blob*, que possui todo o conteúdo do arquivo e é armazenado em `.git/objects`, e a *tree* correspondente ao commit passa a apontar para este novo *blob*. Se um arquivo não foi modificado, a *tree* aponta para o mesmo *blob* que a tree do commit anterior estava apontando.

Conforme o repositório aumenta, em determinado momento (usando heurísticas internas) o Git decide fazer o *packing* dos objetos, criando os *packfiles*. Neste momento alguns objetos ainda serão armazenados em sua totalidade, enquanto outros serão armazenados como deltas em relação a estes.

Um detalhe importante é que as versões mais novas são mantidas intactas, enquanto as mais antigas são deltas tendo a mais nova como base. Isso porque uma versão armazenada como delta precisa ser reconstruída (pegando-se o arquivo base e aplicando os deltas) e isso é mais lento do que acessar o conteúdo todo "não-deltificado", e como é mais provável que você queira acessar as mais novas com mais frequência, optou-se por fazer assim.

Você pode forçar o *packing* através de `git gc` (ou `git gc --aggressive`, que muda alguns parâmetros para fazer um *packing* "mais agressivo"), mas na prática não devemos nos preocupar muito com isso, pois o Git faz o *packing* automaticamente, quando achar necessário.

De qualquer forma, a estrutura básica é:

- Um commit aponta para uma *tree*, que por sua vez aponta para arquivos (objetos *blob*), ou outras *trees* (no caso de ter sub-pastas)
- Se um arquivo não é modificado, várias *trees* apontarão para o mesmo *blob* (no caso, todas as *trees* dos commits nos quais não houve modificação).
- Se um arquivo é modificado, ele cria um novo objeto blob:

  - no caso de ser *loose*, é um novo arquivo (uma nova entrada em `.git/objects`) que possui todo o conteúdo do mesmo
  - no caso de estar no *packfile*, pode ser um *blob* base (com todo o conteúdo do arquivo), ou um delta (a diferença com relação a outro *blob*)

O que muda é a forma como o conteúdo do arquivo é acessado. No caso de *loose objects*, basta ler o respectivo arquivo em `.git/objects`. Já no caso de um delta no *packfile*, ele precisa ser reconstruído a partir do arquivo base.

---

Mais informações:

- [Git Internals - Packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles)
- [Git Internals - Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)
- [Git seems to store the whole file instead of diff, how to avoid that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41482898)
- [Git internals: how does Git store small differences between revisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43359590)
- [Formato do *packfile*](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format)

Comment: +1 Muito bom. A resposta mais completa sobre, na minha opinião

Answer (score 3):

## O que são conjuntos de modificações no Git

*"Conjunto de modificações"* está para ***Changeset***, que não está relacionado com a maneira como o Git guarda as alterações.

Changeset é um conceito fundamental do Git e está presente também em vários outros sistemas de controle de versão de código fonte.

> A idéia básica de um **changeset** é commitar um conjunto de alterações de maneira atômica, ou seja: ou todas alterações do conjunto são commitadas com sucesso, ou nenhuma é. Podemos fazer uma analogia com uma transação de banco de dados que, ou garante a persistência de vários registros de uma vez, ou faz rollback de tudo caso a persistência de um dos registros dê erro.

É fato que changesets no Git vão além dos changesets em outros sistemas de controle de versão. No git você pode, por exemplo, alterar um changeset no repositório! Isto é, no Git você consegue modificar a história das mudanças ocorridas. Naturalmente, há cenários onde isso se aplica e há restrições, mas esta é outra história.

## Como o Git guarda as alterações?

De saída, ele guarda de maneira semelhante a muitos outros sistemas de controle de versão: quando chega um changeset, apenas os arquivos do changeset são guardados. Os arquivos que não foram alterados permanecem lá como estavam. A cada commit o Git registra um **snapshot**, que é o estado do repositório como ele ficou depois deste commit.

Assim como em outros sistemas versionadores, você consegue requisitar o estado do repositório em qualquer ponto do passado, ou seja: você requisita um determinado snapshot. O que o Git te entregará então são os arquivos commitados no ato do registro daquele snapshot e também todos os arquivos que já estavam lá antes, aqueles que não foram modificados pelo commit que deu origem ao snapshot.

Não, o Git não guarda no ato do commit apenas as alterações de cada arquivo. **No ato do commit, o Git guarda todo o conteúdo do arquivo, e não apenas as modificações feitas no arquivo**.

É correto dizer que o Git é capaz de guardar apenas as diferenças entre os commits de um mesmo arquivo em vez de ter que manter o arquivo inteiro mesmo que apenas uma única linha tenha sido modificada?

Sim, é correto. Em momentos oportunos, o Git fará uma espécie de *garbage collection* e, dentre outras coisas, ele também apagará alguns arquivos históricos substituindo-os pelo registro apenas das modificações que aconteceram nestes arquivos entre um commit e outro (*Delta Encoding*). Você também pode forçar este processo quando desejar.

Importante notar que, durante a garbage collection, o Git não substitui os arquivos dos novos commits por seus *delta encoding* mas sim o inverso: ele obtém as alterações a partir do estado mais atual do arquivo para trás, de modo a entregar com mais velocidade a versão mais recente do arquivo (que é provavelmente a que você vai querer na maior parte das vezes).

## Conclusão

*Conjunto de modificações* ou **Changeset** é um conceito que trata da atomicidade do commit e não está diretamente relacionado com a maneira como o Git guarda os arquivos. O Git é um entre muitos sistemas versionadores que utilizam este conceito de changeset.

**Durante o commit, o Git guarda todo o conteúdo do arquivo alterado**, independentemente de o arquivo ter sido muito pouco modificado (apenas uma nova linha, por exemplo).

O Git não precisa salvar uma cópia do repositório a cada commit para garantir a disponibilidade do repositório em algum estado do passado. Ao invés, durante o commit ele registra um **snapshot** que aponta para os arquivos recém commitados e também para as versões atuais dos demais arquivos que já estavam lá.

Em momentos oportunos, o Git reorganiza a sua base a fim de economizar espaço (**garbage collection**). Durante esta reorganização, versões passadas de um arquivo podem ser substuídas por registros apenas das alterações que o arquivo sofreu (**delta encoding**). Assim, quando uma versão antiga for requisitada, o Git reconstrói o arquivo a partir da sua versão mais atual, aplicando nele os registros das mudanças em direção à versão mais antiga.