# Como funcionam as branches no Git em relação ao SVN?

Tags: git

Sabe-se que no SVN, quando se cria uma *[branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html)* (ou até mesmo uma *tag*), é feita uma cópia de **todos os arquivos** do *trunk* para a pasta dentro do diretório ***branches***.

Aos poucos eu venho usando Git e percebi que ao criar uma *[branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)* ele não cria cópia de nenhum arquivo, mas mesmo assim eu consigo editar o mesmo arquivo em duas branches diferentes, ou seja, eu consigo manter duas, ou mais versões do mesmo arquivo.

A minha dúvida é: Como o Git trata essa questão? Qual é a "magia" que o Git faz para conseguir manter "várias versões" do mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Eu não conheço os detalhes por isso não vou responder mas ele trabalha com *deltas* do que você modifica e é só isto que ele precisa. Ele calcula o estado do ramo ao invés de ter cópias.

Comment: Confesso que eu já estava esperando uma resposta tua @bigown

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Ainda aguardando a resposta perfeita?

Comment: @FellipeSoares Sim, é costumeiro eu demorar um certo tempo a aceitar uma resposta. Gosto de dar oportunidades caso mais pessoas queiram responder

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Perguntei justamente pra saber se eu deveria pesquisar mais sobre =) Valeu.

Comment: @FellipeSoares Sua resposta está bem clara, claro que edições/melhorias serão bem aceitas. Mas, realmente é só questão de costume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No fundo, um repositório do Git é um [DAG (*Directed Acyclic Graph*, ou "Grafo Acíclico Dirigido")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Basicamente, são nós apontando para outros. Esses nós podem ser várias coisas: *commits*, *blobs* (bytes que correspondem ao conteúdo de um arquivo), *trees* (estrutura de um diretório, que pode arquivos e/ou outras *trees*), etc.

Cada commit aponta para o(s) commit(s) "pai(s)" - merges podem gerar commits com mais de um pai - e também para uma *tree*, que contém um *snapshot* (uma "fotografia") que corresponde ao estado dos arquivos e diretórios que correspondem àquele commit. Para uma explicação detalhada desta estrutura, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/563536/112052).

[image: repositório Git]

E um branch nada mais é que um ponteiro para um commit. Então quando você cria um branch, basicamente precisa informar o nome dele o e o commit para o qual ele apontará (que pode ou não ser implícito). Por exemplo, se eu quiser criar um branch chamado `novobranch`, posso usar uma dessas opções:

1. `git branch novobranch`
2. `git branch novobranch branch_existente`
3. `git branch novobranch hash_commit` (no caso, `hash_commit` é o hash do commit - aquele "código gigante", como por exemplo `1c6a1bb3c3f0e3235b6eed680ac552bddb703ba9`)

Na opção 1 acima, o branch `novobranch` apontará para o mesmo commit que o HEAD está apontando (leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528332/112052) para saber o que é o HEAD, mas resumindo, é o seu "branch atual").

Na opção 2, `novobranch` apontará para o mesmo commit que `branch_existente` está apontando no momento. E na opção 3, `novobranch` aponta para o commit indicado.

> Claro que existem outras opções, como `HEAD~1` para pegar o commit pai do HEAD, etc. O que importa é que seja algo que resulte em um commit.

Independente da opção escolhida, no final `novobranch` apontará para um commit específico. E para criar este branch, tudo que o Git faz (depois de descobrir qual é o commit para o qual o branch apontará) é criar um arquivo na pasta `.git/refs/heads/`, cujo nome é o mesmo do branch, e o conteúdo é o hash do commit para o qual ele aponta (a pasta `.git/` fica na raiz do seu repositório). Ou seja, em linhas gerais, criar um branch equivale a criar um arquivo com pouquíssimos bytes (atualmente, 40 bytes - mas pode aumentar para 64 caso a [migração para o SHA-256](https://git-scm.com/docs/hash-function-transition/) ocorra, pois na data em que escrevo esta resposta, [ainda é experimental](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init/2.37.3#Documentation/git-init.txt---object-formatltformatgt)).

Por isso que criar um branch é um processo tão leve e rápido. Tudo que o Git faz é criar um novo "label"/"apelido" para um commit específico. Mas o commit em si não muda, pois ele continua apontando para a mesma *tree*, que por sua vez aponta para os mesmos arquivos.

---

> *Qual é a "magia" que o git faz para conseguir manter "várias versões" do mesmo arquivo?*

Isso de certa forma já foi explicado em [O que são realmente os conjuntos de modificações do Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48602/112052)

De forma *bem* resumida, quando você altera um arquivo e faz o commit, o Git cria um novo commit, que aponta para uma nova *tree*, que por sua vez apontará para os arquivos (os que foram modificados apontam para a nova versão do arquivo, enquanto os que não foram modificados continuam apontando para a mesma versão que a *tree* do commit anterior apontava). Para mais detalhes sobre como isso é feito, veja o link indicado no parágrafo anterior.

[image: repositório Git]

E não deixe de ler também a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).

---

Quanto ao SVN, para criar um novo branch você na verdade precisa [criar uma cópia do *trunk* na pasta `branches`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create), algo como:

```bash
svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
         http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
         -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."
```

E repare que o branch é criado remotamente (direto no repositório). Já no Git os branches são locais (sempre criados no seu repositório local), e depois você pode escolher se os envia ou não para algum repositório remoto (via `git push`).

Esta cópia, entretanto, não é feita duplicando dados, pois ela usa o que a [documentação](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html) chama de *cheap copies* (similar ao conceito de [*hard links* do Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29786294), ou seja, são criados "links internos" que apontam para uma árvore de diretórios já existente). Ainda sim, há *benchmarks* que afirmam que um repositório do Git costuma ser menor que um do SVN, mas é algo que [deve ser analisado com cuidado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153627).

Para mais detalhes, ver [aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/344474), [aqui](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison) e [aqui](https://hginit.github.io/00.html).

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta. Eu troquei o aceite porque acredito que os detalhes contidos na sua resposta atendem melhor à pergunta - pelo menos àquilo que eu estava pensando na época (ou como eu lembro).

Talvez não faça sentido você ir atrás de mais informações só para complementar a resposta, mas seria legal ter uma seção (mesmo que pequena) explicando como funciona esse processo no SVN (a cópia dos arquivos, no caso).

Comment: @JéfBueno Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado! Nessa resposta você consegui eliminar minha maior deficiência no uso do GIT, eu não conseguia visualizar o que estava fazendo pois na minha mente eu tentava modelar o arquivo git como uma árvore e o modelo mental nunca condizia com que estava fazendo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Recomendo duas leituras pra complementar: [essa](https://think-like-a-git.net/) e [essa](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified). Depois que entendi que o repositório é um DAG, tudo passou a fazer mais sentido

Answer (score 8):

A resposta está na [documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-O-que-%C3%A9-um-Branch).

A cada `commit`, são criadas *snapshots* daquele mesmo arquivo no diretório do `Git`. As *branches* são como ponteiros que sempre apontam para uma *snapshot*. No exemplo abaixo, vemos a branch **master**.

[image: Fonte: https://git-scm.com/]

Quando se tem duas *branches* (no exemplo, **master** e **testing**, basicamente, temos dois ponteiros, que podem ou não estar apontando para o mesmo `commit`, que por sua vez, aponta para um *snapshot* do arquivo:

[image: Fonte: https://git-scm.com/]

Fonte das imagens: https://git-scm.com/

Isto está em nítido contraste com a forma com a qual a maioria das ferramentas de [versionamento](/questions/tagged/versionamento) gerenciam branches, que envolve a cópia de todos os arquivos do projeto para um segundo diretório.

Isso pode demorar vários segundos ou até minutos, dependendo do tamanho do projeto, enquanto que no `Git` o processo é sempre instantâneo. Também, porque nós estamos gravando os pais dos objetos quando fazemos commits, encontrar uma boa base para fazer o `merge` é uma tarefa feita automaticamente para nós e geralmente é muito fácil de fazer.

Esses recursos ajudam a estimular os desenvolvedores a criar e utilizar branches com frequência.