# Git - Como usar corretamente os branches

Tags: git, versionamento, svn

Estou aprendendo a usar o Git agora, após longa vivência com SVN. 
Não estou compreendendo como usar os *branches* pois, no SVN um *branch* é uma cópia do *trunk* com todos os arquivos.

Com isso, caso eu faça um *branch* para corrigir um problema eu poderei visualizar a aplicação rodando no *trunk* o tempo todo. Basta apontar o *browser* para a pasta correta. Caso eu queira ver o resultado dos ajustes que estou fazendo no *branch* é só fazer a mesma coisa, aponto para a pasta *branch*.

No Git, após criar um branch e editar um arquivo, eu "perco" a visualização do estado anterior da aplicação.

O exemplo descrito abaixo foi retirado do "git-scm.com" :

- crio um *branch* para um erro (`iss91`), trabalho nele um pouco
- crio um segundo *branch* para testar um nova maneira de resolver o mesmo problema (`iss91v2`)
- volto ao meu *master* e trabalho nele por um tempo
- crio um novo *branch* para trabalhar em algo que não sei se é uma boa ideia (`dumbidea`)

O que não entendo é : "quando volto ao meu master e trabalho nele por um tempo" eu já não visualizo como o meu `master` funcionava quando criei o primeiro branch (`iss91`)? Ao rodar minha aplicação nesse momento ela roda com os ajustes feitos no branch `iss91v2`.

Como devo usar isso? Como funciona esse fluxo de trabalho ?

**UPDATE:** A dúvida é como visualizar diferentes implementações para resolver um problema em diferentes *branches* uma vez que, após fazer uma edição no branch `iss91v2`, se eu der um `git checkout qualquer_outro_branch` e rodar a aplicação eu não visualizarei o resultado das implementações daquele *branch*. Eu só verei o sistema com os ajustes feitos no branch `iss91v2`.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80583/101,

Comment: Possívelmente respondida em [Qual é a diferença entre um branch e uma tag?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80583/70)

Comment: Infelizmente não ajudou. Essas informações eu entendi. Acho que a pergunta acaba sendo : após eu fazer um branch eu não tenho mais acesso à versão anterior a menos que eu dê um "reset" para sumir com os commits que fiz no branch ? Tipo : o endereço do projeto é o mesmo, mas a partir do momento que crio e modifico um branch, ao entrar no endereço eu só visualizo o projeto com as modificações do branch. Se eu quiser visualizar o que o projeto fazia antes não é possível, porque ele agora mostra os ajustes que fiz no branch. Não entendi como usar a alternância entre um branch e outro.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como funcionam as branches no GIT em relação ao SVN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87741/18246)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> volto ao meu master e trabalho nele por um tempo

Talvez aqui esteja a chave do sua dificuldade. Os padrões mais comuns de uso do Git em geral não incentivam que você trabalhe diretamente no seu branch principal. `master` ou `develop` costumam ser coleções de coisas que você desenvolveu nos seus branches e, quando prontas, você incorporou ali.

Trazendo isso para o contexto da sua pergunta, seu fluxo poderia ser algo assim:

- cria um branch para um erro (iss91) e trabalha nele
- volta para o master
- cria um outro branch pra testar outra forma de resolver o mesmo problema (iss91v2)
- volta para o master
- cria um branch pra algo que não relacionado (naorel), trabalha até estar ok
- volta para o master, dá merge em `naorel`, agora `master` está um passo à frente dos seus outros branches.

Agora se você quiser visualizar `iss91` basta dar checkout nele. Se quiser ver `iss91v2` basta dar checkout nele.

Você decidiu então que `iss91v2` é a melhor forma pra resolver o outro problema então você faz:

```
$ git checkout iss91v2
$ git merge master
```

Agora `iss91v2` tem também as alterações que você incluiu em `naorel` mas não tem as de `iss91`. Se quiser você pode testar `iss91` com as alterações de `naorel` da mesma forma.

O histórico é bem flexível, basta saber exatamente em qual ponto você quer chegar.

Aí sim, quando estiver satisfeito(a) você pode fazer

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge iss91v2
```

e seguir a vida.